# How many photos can I display on a webpage

Tags: php, iphone, web, browser, single-page-application

I'm using a motion detect security camera, which will upload all its captured photos via FTP, to my hosting service. To view and manage the photos, I created a PHP file which will allow me to either display all the photos or delete them all. This is just being used to make sure my cats are OK when I'm traveling. So the PHP file will simply display each file name, timestamp, and the photo, with maximum screen width, since I'll be viewing on a little i-phone.

My question is, do i need to add code to limit the number of photos on the page it creates? Or can I depend on the browser to be smart enough to just load the part of the page its displaying, discarding what is not visible. I need to know this because if one of the cats decides to roll around the floor for an hour at a time, and I don't get to check if for a full day, it feasible I could have 500+ images.

I guess its not that big a deal to add a maximum image limit in my form that controls the PHP code, but if browsers can automatically handle ridiculous size pages, that's one less thing to deal with

EDIT: after some experimentation I was surprised to find that (a) all my PC based browsers (even a lowly I-8) and mobile devices (including my ancient I-phone-4) had little trouble displaying 1000 images, at about 1024 x 780. BUT... (b) browsing through them (especially on a mobile device) was ridiculously tedious, and had I not been on wiFI, I'd have paid for all that data download. So the bottom line non quantified answer to "how many" on modern devices seems to be "a lot more than you'd ever have time to view".

So in the end I added a bit more to my display form and code, so I could view a reasonable number of images at a time, choose how many photos per/page, sort (forward or reverse) by time stamp, and a few other niceties. Everyone's comments wewre indeed helpful

Comment: The browser will load everything, it will *not* limit to just the photos that fit. You might want to add some sort of pagination.

Comment: You might also consider something like [Infinite Scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/), which will fill the page and then load extras as you keep scrolling. Sounds closer to what you want.

Comment: Wait... dude... Randy Constan? Flippin' legend! What's up! :)

Comment: This is not a code issue, but a device issue. If you want to load 500+ images, the devices browser will need to be able to render them all. This A) uses a lot of network traffic, and B) uses memory resources to load the page. On a desktop computer, this is less of an issue, yet will create performance issues. On an iPhone, this can create performance issues. The browser might crash or stop responding well... So I suggest you consider how this will effect your target audience and build around what is going to provide a positive experience for the user.

Comment: Well I'm the only target audience in this case, since I'm just monitoring my cats! :-) But I guess I could determine the total before hand, and just have a couple of default fields for the start and max. Damn though... i was hoping not to have to do all that, I see people with their phones scrolling through what looks like hundreds of photos, and I thought for sure the browser was keeping track of what actually needed to be loaded and displayed. Oh well! :-)

Comment: _"thought for sure the browser was keeping track"_ Well, to be clear, the browser *can* do that, just not with pure HTML. You need some javascript to detect when the page scrolls and then AJAX load the next set of photos.

Comment: @AlexHowansky - Ah that makes sense. Well this is just a PHP file that generates the page as its parsing through the available pictures. So I'll have to keep it simple. But then all things start as a simple "proof of concept', and no sooner that realizing it works, the "simple" project mushrooms. But something like you're talking about has probably been done often enough that I probably could find something already done. Now that I understand that there IS a problem anyway.

Comment: @AlexHowansky And I'd better master this stuff before I embark on updating that "Legendary"web site you probably remember me from! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will load everything that's present in the html. So, you will have to limit the number of images uploaded yourself, maybe add a filter so it uploads only one image every 5 minutes.

Comment: really appreciate it! well that's internet at its best! I am not a pro coder but this project sounds interesting, I would love to follow it and maybe chip in if I can...will be a good learning curve.

Comment: I've been banned from posting on Stackoverflow for 6 months, so I won't be here much for a while. But if you're interested in the PHP code for the finished project, IM me and I'll happily send you the code. It has enough comments to be pretty self explanatory,

Comment: sure, let me do that